# php function to detect that site is open in mobile phone or in computer browser

Tags: php, function

I need a php function which will help me to detect that user is logged-in from his mobile phone or from his computer? Is there a way to detect this?

I have tried with `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` but It returns a string with browser name and mobile name with specification. for exampe for website it returns :- 
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0`

Comment: `preg_match('/mobile/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look this library - [MobileDetect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)

You can then use it like :

```
// These lines are mandatory.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
// Basic detection.
$detect->isMobile();
$detect->isTablet();
```